# Compute intersection coordinates of two vectors moving on different speeds

Tags: javascript

The red dot is moving at speed 400 in direction of the green dot.
I want to move the yellow dot to the coordinates of the red dot after the time needed for the yellow dot to reach the position.

In other words, I want the yellow dot to intercept the red one to make them overlap before the red dot reaches the green dot coordinates.

[image]

I'm using this function to get the distance between dots:

```
function getDistance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
}
```

And this one to normalize the distances taking into account the speeds:

```
function normalizeDistance(distance, speed) {
    return distance / speed;
}
```

But I can't find out how to obtain the information I need.

I logically know the coordinates of the 3 dots and I know that the red dot is going to head in the coordinates of the green one.
The green dot is static.

How can I do?

**Edit**:

To clarify, here's simpler examples for the same problem:

[image: img]

---

[image]

Comment: That's a difficult one. In your example, the longer it takes the yellow dot to reach the red dot, the further the red dot will have travelled and, because it's going vaguely towards the yellow dot, the less time it takes the yellow dot to get there. Consider the scenario in which the three dots are perfectly aligned (yellow, green, red), what happens?

Comment: If the 3 dots are perfectly aligned I think it should be easier right? No need to account for the trajectory.

http://i.imgur.com/pAvbJFk.png

Comment: i recommend you to ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com first, and if theres a good solution there, bounty this one with additional data on how to do this in a match way...

Comment: Thank you I'll do!

Comment: I posted the question here for anyone interested:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347345/compute-intersection-coordinates-of-two-vectors-moving-on-different-speeds

Comment: I got a reply on the math question, gonna bounty this tomorrow to get a reply that makes the algorithm work in JS

Answer (score 1):

One option is to narrow it down until you get a "close enough" answer.

First figure out how long it takes for Yellow to get to where Red is. In that time, Red will of course have travelled towards Green, but that's fine.

Figure out how long it will take if Yellow had gone for where Red ended up.

This might be longer (if Red is moving generally away from Yellow) or it might be shorter (if Red is moving generally towards Yellow).

Either way, use this to figure out where Red ended up and get a new target. Keep adjusting towards the new target until you get "close enough" to Red that's acceptable.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f8uq8kka/) with configuration options available

The general idea will be (pseudocode):

```
epsilon = 0.01
red_angle = Math.atan2(green.y - red.y, green.x - red.x)

target = {x:red.x, y:red.y}
distance = pythagoras(target.x - yellow.x, target.y - yellow.y)
time = distance / yellow.speed
redmoved = time * red.speed
newtarget = {
  x: red.x + redmoved * Math.cos(red_angle),
  y: red.y + redmoved * Math.sin(red_angle)
}
delta = pythagoras(target.x - newtarget.x, target.y - newtarget.y)
// repeat while delta > epsilon or after a reasonable maximum number of steps
```

Comment: Cool! Your demo takes a lot of time to "guess" the right position tho. Is this related to something you added to slow it down to see the process or is it really that slow?

Comment: It uses `setTimeout(iterate, 1000)` to put a 1-second gap between guesses, for visualisation.

Comment: Right! That's perfect (I guess?)

Comment: I don't know if it's perfect, that's up to you to give the algorithm a try in your application and see if it works for you ;) It's worth noting that the "max steps" is important, because if Yellow can't catch Red (for instance, Red outruns Yellow somehow) then there needs to be a reasonable limit to give up.

Comment: Actually I'm going to use it to improve my Zombies killer "AI" [here](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/code-vs-zombies).

You may want to give it a try as well 

Comment: For something like that, you could actually have quite a big epsilon, since "anywhere within X range" is enough to kill a zombie.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to keep the question focused on the problem, gonna tweak the algorithm!